# Flask-Admin: How to filter selectable data of a field based on values entered in the previous field, with search conditions in another table

Tags: filter, field, relationship, flask-admin

in flask-admin model view I want to filter a dropdown menu in the edit/create view of field that is a relationship, based on values entered in the previous field.
In the specific case, I would like to see only the ones in the "posto" that are displayed in another table belonging to the selected 'categoria'

```py
class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    nr_TAG = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    categoria_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categorie.id'), nullable=False)
    categoria = db.relationship('Categoria', backref='tags')
    posto_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('stalli.id'), nullable=False)
    posto = db.relationship('Stallo', backref='tags')
    cognome = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    nome = db.Column(db.String(30))
    auto = db.Column(db.String(20))
    targa = db.Column(db.String(10))
    recapito = db.Column(db.String(80))
    stato = db.Column(db.Integer)
    posto_occ = db.Column(db.Integer)
    orario = db.Column(db.Integer)
    fuoriposto = db.Column(db.String(10))
    parcheggio = db.Column(db.String(40))

class TagsAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    can_edit = True
    can_create = True
    column_list = ['nr_TAG', 'categoria', 'posto', 'cognome', 'targa',
                        'stato', 'orario', 'fuoriposto', 'parcheggio']
    can_view_details = True
    details_modal = True
    form_columns = ['nr_TAG', 'categoria', 'posto', 'cognome', 'nome', 'auto', 'targa', 'recapito']
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: I think you will need to load all values in your dropdown menu and use Javascript to filter the values depending on the user input value.

Comment: Do you have any such example? In fact I think it's a good idea

Answer (score 0):

I came up with following solution, maybe it's not perfect but it does the job:

**master.html**

```js
function populateSelectField(to_populate, options, select) {
  $('#s2id_' + to_populate + ' > a > span').text('');

  var el = $('select[name$="' + to_populate + '"]');
  el.children().remove();

  option = '<option value=""></option>';
  el.append($(option));

  options.forEach(function(row) {
    var option_id = row.id,
      option_title = row.title;

    if (select && option_id == select) {
      option = '<option value="' + option_id + '" selected>' + option_title + '</option>';
      $('#s2id_' + to_populate + ' > a > span').text(option_title);
    } else {
      option = '<option value="' + option_id + '">' + option_title + '</option>';
    }

    el.append($(option));
  });
}

function getOptions(el, to_populate, url, select) {
  var item_id = el.val(),
    url = window.location.origin + url + item_id + '/';

  $.get(url).done(function(options) {
    populateSelectField(to_populate, options, select);
  }).fail(function(err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return false;
  });
}

function selectFieldManipulation(from_populate, to_populate, url) {
  var main_select = $('select[name$="' + from_populate + '"]'),
    to_populate_el = $('select[name$="' + to_populate + '"]');

  getOptions(main_select, to_populate, url, to_populate_el.val());

  main_select.change(function(e) {
    getOptions(main_select, to_populate, url, null);
  });
}
```

**create.html** / **edit.html**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  selectFieldManipulation('from_populate', 'to_populate', '/api/route_to_view/');
});
```